# How to get Local IP address and proxy server of client

Tags: php, javascript, proxy, ip, cgi

I read many articles suggesting to use http_x_forwarded_for to get proxy server and real ip address of client but none of them seem to be working.

I am assigned a local IP address and i use Proxy server to connect to internet. But When i displayed whole $_SERVER variable there was not a single trace of my Real Machine IP and Proxy server used by me.

This [LINK](http://noone.comuf.com/) shows whole $_SERVER variable.

I guess it is not possible in PHP. How do i accomplish this? I know its possible because once i saw some webpage displaying my real IP address and Proxy server used by me in Mozilla. But not sure which language it was using.

How do i accomplish? I am ready to use CGI or JavaScript. I couldn't found any working example on internet. Help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's entirely up to the proxy as to whether or not it will send the `http_x_forwarded_for` header. Some will and some won't. Whichever proxy you were using when you printed the `$_SERVER` variable, hasn't send the header.

Even if all proxies did send the header, you would still have a problem because anyone can spoof the `http_x_forwarded_for` header and so if your script treats that as the real IP, then someone could spoof it to circumvent your IP check.

The best you can do if use `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` and forget about relying on `http_x_forwarded_for`. Yes users of proxies will be able to visit your site under a new IP, but this is better than the ability for all users to spoof the IP in `http_x_forwarded_for`.

As an aid you could maintain a list of known proxies but again this won't ultimately give you the real client IP, it could only tell you if the IP is in your proxy list.

Comment: I understand, but if there is any way to run a javascript on client machine to get IP and proxy from browser? If its is possible of course!

Comment: Unfortunately no, you can include an external script but that will have the same problem as your PHP of whether or not it relies on the actual IP or the `x_forwarded_for`. Also see my edit about keeping a list of proxies.

Answer (score 1):

I found that the little switch I wrote solved the problem for most people that had trouble getting the real ip rather than a proxy.  It checks if the `REMOTE_ADDR` and the `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR` are the same and if they are, it prints the `REMOTE_ADDR`.  If they are different, it assumes that the `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR` is right because the `REMOTE_ADDR` usually returns the proxy.  Hope this helps.  Please let me know if there is a better way! kevin@tiger-tech.tk

```
  <?php 
  $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
  $ip2 = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];

  switch($ip): 
  case $ip2: 
        $ipa = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
        $city= file_get_contents ("http://ipinfo.io/".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']."/city");
        $region= file_get_contents ("http://ipinfo.io/".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']."/region");
        $geo= file_get_contents ("http://ipinfo.io/".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']."/geo");
        break;
  default:
        $ipa = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
        $city= file_get_contents ("http://ipinfo.io/".$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']."/city");
        $region= file_get_contents ("http://ipinfo.io/".$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']."/region");
        $geo= file_get_contents ("http://ipinfo.io/".$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']."/geo");
        break;
  endswitch;
   ?>
```